# What is the purpose of calling (0, func)() in JS?

Tags: javascript

I came across this in [code generated by Babel](https://unpkg.com/redux-immutable@4.0.0/dist/combineReducers.js) from [this source](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L29). It would appear to be guarding a required function, somehow.

```
(0, _utilities.validateNextState)(nextDomainState, reducerName, action);
```

I understand how the comma statement in the parenthesis discards the `0` and returns the `validateNextState` function, but why not just do:

```
_utilities.validateNextState(nextDomainState, reducerName, action);
```

My guess is a type of guard (like closures guard scope, or setTimeout makes a function call asynchronous), but can't figure out what it's purpose is.

Comment: Probably to avoid setting `this` to `_utilities` inside the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sometimes mystifying semantics of JavaScript are probably the reason. The expression

```
(0, _utilities.validateNextState)
```

evaluates of course to a reference to that function. However, because it's in that parenthesized subexpression, the function call that's outside that will be made *without* that `_utilities` object being recognized as the context for the call (the `this` value). Thus inside the `validateNextState` function, `this` will be either `undefined` or a reference to the global object, depending on the "strict" mode state.

I suspect that Babel does that because in the original source code the call to `validateNextState()` is made as if it were a "naked" function, not a method on an object. Babel doesn't know (probably) whether the value of `this` matters to that particular function, but it has to make sure it gets invoked safely.

Comment: But why not just `(_utilities.validateNextState)(args)`? Edit: Apparently this will not have that effect but I have no idea why.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 JavaScript is weird.

Comment: You forgot the ™ @Pointy :p